# Book read in the '80s or '90s about lovers who were either time travelers or reincarnated

Tags: story-identification, books, magic, reincarnation

I’m looking for a book that I read in the '80s or '90s about lovers who were either time travelers or reincarnated. They had a lot of fights, they went out with other people, and it seems like there was magic or sorcery in it as well.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. So was this like an on-again-off-again relationship, with the two lovers reuniting again and again in different time periods? And do recall anything else about the main characters, such as their jobs or backgrounds, or the circumstances in which they first met?

Comment: Incidentally, if anyone correctly identifies the book you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Were they men or women or one of each, or did they change gender between reincarnations? Were there just two of them?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ken Grimwood's 1986 novel *[Replay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_(Grimwood_novel))* may fit the bill. Jeff Winston dies of a heart attack in 1988 and suddenly wakes up in his 18-year-old body in 1963. He has a chance to relive his life without making the same mistakes...He makes different ones. Then he dies in 1988 again and wakes up young again (at a later date). Lather, rinse, repeat.

Along the way he meets Pamela Phillips, who is apparently experiencing the same thing. They fall in love; and in some iterations they are together, but  the advancing start time of the replays means they're further along in their original lives and the window is steadily closing.